# Does the passage from Deuteronomy 17:5-7 regarding idolatry also establish legal principles for other cases?

Tags: deuteronomy

Does the passage from Deuteronomy 17:5-7 regarding idolatry also establish legal principles for other cases, such as the adulterous woman mentioned in the New Testament John 8:5?

Deuteronomy 17:5-7 KJV

> <sup>**5**</sup> Then shalt thou bring forth that man or that woman, which have committed that wicked thing, unto thy gates, even that man or that woman, and shalt stone them with stones, till they die. <sup>**6**</sup> At the mouth of two witnesses, or three witnesses, shall he that is worthy of death be put to death; but at the mouth of one witness he shall not be put to death. <sup>**7**</sup> The hands of the witnesses shall be first upon him to put him to death, and afterward the hands of all the people. So thou shalt put the evil away from among you.

Comment: What legal principle?

Comment: Why would the passage referring to idolatry automatically refer to adultery ?

Comment: @Dottard I think the OP refers to "At the mouth of two witnesses, or three witnesses, shall he that is worthy of death be put to death; but at the mouth of one witness he shall not be put to death."

Comment: @Nigel It doesn't do so automatically. The OP  asks if this was a precedent that established a general rule (see 19:6). The question could be clearer but I think it's quite interesting.

Comment: @DanFefferman I don't see why any precept should 'set a precedent' for another matter and especially establish any kind of 'general rule'. I don't see the relevance of Deut 19:6. Law just doesn't work like this.

Comment: Thank you. 19:6 was a mistake . It was supposed to be 19:15. Also precedent was a poor word choice on my part. The question was whether the principle established for idolatry also applied generally (as in 19:15). About how law works, I do think there was an evolution in the practice of the law during the 40 years in the wilderness, as indicated in Exodus 18, where minor judges ruled most cases and brought the difficult ones to Moses. I picture I kind of praxis, in which the Lord and Moses functioned as a kind of appeals court based on the experience of applying the Law revealed at Sinai.

Comment: So one could see Dt. as a new iteration of the Law based on 40 years of  Israelite jurisprudence. Ex 18:26  says "They rendered decisions for the people in all routine cases. The more difficult cases they referred to Moses, but all the lesser cases they settled themselves. " This implies refined legal principles based on adjudication, just as in modern law. The fundamentals did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider the order of the text, the answer appears to be yes, for the "two witnesses" principle is first mentioned here - especially if one considers other translations of vs. 6:

- Only on the testimony of two or three witnesses shall a person be put to death; no one shall be put to death on the testimony of only one witness. (NABRE)
- On the testimony of two or three witnesses a person is to be put to death, but no one is to be put to death on the testimony of only one witness. (NIV)

But Dt. 19:15 specifically establishes the principle as a general legal procedure:

> 15 One witness alone shall not stand against someone in regard to any
> crime or any offense that may have been committed; a charge shall
> stand only on the testimony of two or three witnesses.

However, the text also explains that Deuteronomy is a new iteration of the Law expressed only after the 40 years in the wilderness.

> These are the words that Moses spoke to all Israel beyond the Jordan
> in the wilderness, in the Arabah, opposite Suph, between Paran and
> Tophel, Laban, Hazeroth, and Dizahab. (Dt. 1:1)

In that sense the principle could have been practiced during the wilderness period prior to its formal expression in Deuteronomy. This would also be the case if the book was composed much later, as the editors of the [NABRE translation](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/deuteronomy/0) suggest:

> The book was probably composed over the course of three centuries,
> from the eighth century to the exile and beyond. It bears some
> relation to “the Book of the Law” discovered in the Jerusalem Temple
> around 622 B.C. during the reign of King Josiah (2 Kgs 22:8–13).

**Conclusion**: this a chicken-and-egg question that has no definite answer. Deuteronomy is described in the text itself as a second telling of the law by Moses 40 years after the Sinai event. That being the case, the general principle of "two witnesses" may have already been practiced by the Israelites during their 40 years in the wilderness. But in terms of the text itself, Dt. 17:6 is the first mention of it.

Comment: Then there is also 2 Cor 13:1, Matt 18:16, Heb 10:28, 1 Tim 5:19 that confirms it is a legal principle.